# Was a German WWI soldier made into a hat rack by a furious Scottish Lord?

Tags: history, world-war-i

In the TV show [QI XL J16 - Just the Job](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n8w6XbHB5W8) Jeremy Clarkson tells a story, about a Scottish Lord making a hat rack out of a german WWI soldier. The story goes (from 21:20 in the video):

> There were some people looking around an Auction at a Scottish Lords castle for a WWI German Soldier who had been made into a hat-stand. 
>   Apparently the Lord had a batman/valet who was something more than just a servant to him who was killed in WWI. The lord was so enraged that he went across the trenches shot and dragged back the German soldier and had him made into a hat-stand.

<sup>Transcription taken from the forum discussion below</sup>

The only think I found related to the story is [this](http://old.qi.com/talk/viewtopic.php?t=26858&start=0&sid=f25154c9691dd94afdc59f8cee55b64e) forum discussion, which starts as a request to corroborate the story, but eventually only discusses its legal implications.

Is there any truth to the story?

Comment: Well it *is* Clarkson, whose been known to exaggerate for comedic purposes.http://www.theguardian.com/media/2013/mar/05/top-gear-tesla-jeremy-clarkson

Comment: @SystemDown, but he did say before telling the story that this is not a joke, but a true story.

Comment: "he went across the trenches shot and dragged back the German soldier" ... that was a hell of a lord, breaching the german trenches, killing a specified soldier and carrying him back across the no man's land :D

Comment: Well, he was a Scot! ;)